# Is it safe to kill the Python process when writing to a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When opening a file for writing, is there any point in time where the file contents would be erased if the process was killed?

Here is the code used:

```py
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()

data = modify(data)

with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Comment: You're not opening a file for writing here. What mode are you actually using? And have you read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) already? You'll get a different answer between `'w'` and `'x'` for example.

Comment: Your question is going to attract highly opinionated answers. Do you have a specific reason for killing a program while it is writing to a file? Or are you thinking of a specific scenario where a file is being written to and the program is prematurely terminated? Please include more details in your question. Thanks

Comment: If you exit the program using `ctrl+c`  then no.  If you literally kill the process then that is considered undefined behaviour, and there is really no guarantee.  But in most cases you would still be fine

Comment: @Alexander: Ctrl-C isn't safe either.

Comment: @user2357112  when ctrl+c is triggered it raises the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception in the python script, and since the OP is using the `with open(...)` expression uncaught exceptions force the file to close.  So it's definitely safer than killing the process completely

Comment: @Alexander: It'll force a `close`, but that'll just flush buffers. It won't write any data that hasn't been written or buffered yet.

Comment: @user2357112  The OP specifically asks if killing the process would erase the contents of the file.  All of my comments are framed from that context.

Comment: @Alexander: Just opening the file for writing erases the contents. If the process is killed between then and when writing finishes, you get an empty or partially-written file. Killing the process may not itself be what erases the file, but I think the question was about if killing the process could leave the file empty, not if killing the process would directly erase the contents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's unsafe. Kill the process between the `open("file.txt", "w")` and the point stuff starts getting written, and the file will be empty. Kill it while data is getting written, and the file can end up in a half-written state.

Programs that need to be safe about this kind of thing do it by writing output data to a new file, and then replacing the original file with the new file once the data has been fully written and flushed.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I suspected. Normally I would have used ctrl-c and exception handling, but VScode has made me used to the close process button.

Comment: @WanderingCoder: Ctrl-C has the same problems. It'll run context manager cleanup, but that just closes the file and flushes buffers. It won't actually write any data that didn't get written or buffered yet. If your Ctrl-C hits between the `open` and the `write`, or in the middle of the `write`, you can still end up with an empty or half-written file.